# How to reuse figures and axes created with subplot(num= ... )

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function I want to use several times to plot data **in the same** Figure/Axis.
The function `toto()` in the following code works fine. I use  `plt.figure(num='Single plot')` which check, whenever it is called, if a figure with id 'Single plot' as been already created. If yes, the same figure is **reused** (the figure instance is global I think) :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def toto(x, y):
    plt.figure('Single plot')
    plt.plot(x, y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2)    
toto(x, x)
toto(x, x**2)
plt.show()
```

[image: toto results]

Now, I want to use `subplot()`instead of `figure()` because it will be more useful for me. This function would be :

```
def toto2(x, y):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(num='Single plot 2')
    axes.plot(x, y)
```

But the result is not as expected at all : y ticks are overprinted and the linear line is not plotted (or as been overprinted).

I'd like to understand the rationale behind this and what to modify so that it works as expected.

[image: toto2 results]

Comment: because `plt.subplots` makes a new subplot over the old one.  If you want the old one, do `ax=plt.gca()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you execute `plt.subplots`, you create a new figure and a new set of axes. If you want to reuse the figure, you should create the `fig` and `axes` objects outside of your function, and pass them as argument to your function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def toto3(fig, axes, x, y):
    axes.plot(x, y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(num='Single plot 2')
toto3(fig, axes, x, x)
toto3(fig, axes, x, x**2)
plt.show()
```

(in this case, you could even simplify your code to only pass `axes` to your function, but the idea is applicable to both the `fig` and the `axes` objects)

Comment: Thanks you. So, using `plt.subplots()`, there is no way to use a kind of global variable that would store the `fig` or `axes` like in `plt.figure()`. Maybe it is not that bad because using such implicit global variables, even if it is convenient, can be confusing.

Comment: You could place `fig, axes = plt.subplots()` at the top of the code (immediately after the `import` statements) to make them global and therefore accessible within functions without having to pass them to the function, but indeed, this can very quickly make your code confusing.